# Google Appengine Fail - npm error with make and INVALID_ARGUMENT error

Tags: debugging, google-app-engine, npm, gyp

I'm getting a weird error when I try to deploy google appengine. I've tried removing the yarn files, the package and package lock files, rerunning `npm install`, running `npm cache verify,` `env V=1 npm install fsevents` etc and I'm hopelessly stumped. Would love another eye to look at this, thanks!

There seems to be a few different errors, relating to 'make' and 'fsevents', so i guess that's a pattern here. There's also an issue with an instance class, I dont know what that means though:

:

```
appengine % ./gradlew :...:appengineDeploy -PgaeAppId=[...] -PgaeVersion=[...] --stacktrace

> Configure project :datastore-scrubber
Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'maven' was added by build file 'datastore-scrubber/build.gradle'
Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'maven2' was added by build file 'datastore-scrubber/build.gradle'

> Configure project :[...]
tesType is:normal
tesType is:normal

> Configure project :[...]
tesType is:normal
tesType is:normal

> Configure project :...:appengine
--------------
Preparing [...]
    Project: [...]
     Module: default
    Version: [...]
   Instance: 0
    BuildId: 327f45c7-pd
    ClientType: adsApi
--------------

> Task :[...]:npmInstall

> fsevents@1.2.13 install /Users/.../src/main/webapp-src/community/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents
> node install.js

2022-07-13 17:22:50.815 xcodebuild[69427:3693627] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
2022-07-13 17:22:50.817 xcodebuild[69427:3693627] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/.node
clang: warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++ with a minimum deployment target of OS X 10.9 [-Wdeprecated]
ld: library not found for -lstdc++
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Release/.node] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/.../appengine/.../src/main/webapp-src/community/.gradle/npm/npm-v5.10.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:219:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/.../appengine/.../src/main/webapp-src/community/.gradle/nodejs/node-v6.17.1-darwin-x64/bin/node" "/Users/.../appengine/.../src/main/webapp-src/community/.gradle/npm/npm-v5.10.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/.../appengine/.../src/main/webapp-src/community/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v6.17.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 

> fsevents@1.2.13 install /Users/.../appengine/.../src/main/webapp-src/community/node_modules/gulp-nodemon/node_modules/glob-watcher/node_modules/fsevents
> node install.js

2022-07-13 17:22:57.221 xcodebuild[69462:3693914] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
2022-07-13 17:22:57.222 xcodebuild[69462:3693914] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/.node
clang: warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++ with a minimum deployment target of OS X 10.9 [-Wdeprecated]
ld: library not found for -lstdc++
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Release/.node] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/.../appengine/.../src/main/webapp-src/community/.gradle/npm/npm-v5.10.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:219:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/.../appengine/.../src/main/webapp-src/community/.gradle/nodejs/node-v6.17.1-darwin-x64/bin/node" "/Users/.../appengine/.../src/main/webapp-src/community/.gradle/npm/npm-v5.10.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/.../appengine/.../src/main/webapp-src/community/node_modules/gulp-nodemon/node_modules/glob-watcher/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v6.17.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 

> fsevents@1.2.13 install /Users/.../appengine/.../src/main/webapp-src/community/node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents
> node install.js

2022-07-13 17:23:02.257 xcodebuild[69495:3694117] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
2022-07-13 17:23:02.259 xcodebuild[69495:3694117] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/.node
clang: warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++ with a minimum deployment target of OS X 10.9 [-Wdeprecated]
ld: library not found for -lstdc++
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Release/.node] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/.../appengine/.../src/main/webapp-src/community/.gradle/npm/npm-v5.10.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:219:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/.../appengine/.../src/main/webapp-src/community/.gradle/nodejs/node-v6.17.1-darwin-x64/bin/node" "/Users/.../appengine/.../src/main/webapp-src/community/.gradle/npm/npm-v5.10.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/.../appengine/.../src/main/webapp-src/community/node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v6.17.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 

> base62@1.2.7 postinstall /Users/.../appengine/.../src/main/webapp-src/community/node_modules/base62
> node scripts/install-stats.js || exit 0


> es5-ext@0.10.61 postinstall /Users/.../appengine/.../src/main/webapp-src/community/node_modules/es5-ext
>  node -e "try{require('./_postinstall')}catch(e){}" || exit 0


> nodemon@2.0.19 postinstall /Users/.../appengine/.../src/main/webapp-src/community/node_modules/gulp-nodemon/node_modules/nodemon
> node bin/postinstall || exit 0


> history@1.17.0 postinstall /Users/.../appengine/.../src/main/webapp-src/community/node_modules/history
> node ./npm-scripts/postinstall.js


> nodemon@1.15.1 postinstall /Users/.../appengine/.../src/main/webapp-src/community/node_modules/nodemon
> node -e "console.log('\u001b[32mLove nodemon? You can now support the project via the open collective:\u001b[22m\u001b[39m\n > \u001b[96m\u001b[1mhttps://opencollective.com/nodemon/donate\u001b[0m\n')" || exit 0

Love nodemon? You can now support the project via the open collective:
 > https://opencollective.com/nodemon/donate


> react-router@1.0.3 postinstall /Users/.../appengine/.../src/main/webapp-src/community/node_modules/react-router
> node ./npm-scripts/postinstall.js


> history@1.13.1 postinstall /Users/.../appengine/.../src/main/webapp-src/community/node_modules/redux-simple-router/node_modules/history
> node ./npm-scripts/postinstall.js

(node:69370) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 SIGINT listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
<===npm WARN CGC@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN CGC@1.0.0 No license field.
npm WARN The package gulp is included as both a dev and production dependency.
npm WARN The package react is included as both a dev and production dependency.
npm WARN The package react-google-maps is included as both a dev and production dependency.

added 1441 packages from 828 contributors in 109.328s
[!] 107 vulnerabilities found [1435 packages audited]
    Severity: 10 Low | 37 Moderate | 45 High | 15 Critical
    Run `npm audit` for more detail


> Task :...:community:installGulp
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
/Users/.../appengine/.../src/main/webapp-src/community/.gradle/nodejs/node-v6.17.1-darwin-x64/bin/gulp -> /Users/.../appengine/.../src/main/webapp-src/community/.gradle/nodejs/node-v6.17.1-darwin-x64/lib/node_modules/gulp-cli/bin/gulp.js
+ gulp-cli@2.3.0
updated 1 package in 14.783s

> Task :...:community:gulp_compile
[17:23:37] Using gulpfile ~/appengine/.../src/main/webapp-src/community/gulpfile.js
[17:23:37] Starting 'clean'...
[17:23:37] Finished 'clean' after 139 ms
[17:23:37] Starting 'compile-dev'...
[17:23:39] Finished 'compile-dev' after 1.88 s
[17:23:39] Starting 'build'...
[17:23:39] Finished 'build' after 45 μs
[17:24:04] [webpack] Hash: b01eec9b9b215740e23f
Version: webpack 1.15.0
Time: 24703ms
                                 Asset           Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
  b2fd09d2d6e7ce1b328ead20a178e92b.svg        1.16 kB          [emitted]  
  fa4f68bc1ae76084810c59bdfd838ce5.svg      297 bytes          [emitted]  
  873ecd9c5293d504c3525d348848dacc.svg         109 kB          [emitted]  
  e18bbf611f2a2e43afc071aa2f4e1512.ttf        45.4 kB          [emitted]  
 fa2772327f55d8198301fdb8bcfc8158.woff        23.4 kB          [emitted]  
448c34a56d699c29117adc64c43affeb.woff2          18 kB          [emitted]  
  ff91b2ead3bdcb704102a3750daa8db6.svg        2.29 kB          [emitted]  
  5be796adcb6355893130a01594579430.svg        1.38 kB          [emitted]  
  a6dce5d152826a4eef514aa5a344bd2c.svg        1.58 kB          [emitted]  
  31ec490d5b132c71180a22acac41ddd1.svg      842 bytes          [emitted]  
  132b63502ff1aa2c6e2ab92a1571ec07.svg        2.29 kB          [emitted]  
  b35f3f021292331b1f871289333e8d00.svg      815 bytes          [emitted]  
  f4769f9bdb7466be65088239c12046d1.eot        20.1 kB          [emitted]  
  fb2b314f1f11b897d298e53ca5556ef8.svg        1.38 kB          [emitted]  
  cab33a29ba7c9ff19789abc3f6d11dfa.svg        1.58 kB          [emitted]  
  3d185c654eba9403898313140e6ade9f.svg      842 bytes          [emitted]  
  0e1f36d20f6a179798b236581ca3d745.svg      850 bytes          [emitted]  
  1de25592aed1d35f983658132ea3719c.png        33.3 kB          [emitted]  
                              index.js        2.83 MB       0  [emitted]  main
                               app.css         233 kB       0  [emitted]  main
                          index.js.map        3.41 MB       0  [emitted]  main
                           app.css.map       84 bytes       0  [emitted]  main
                           favicon.ico  NaN undefined          [emitted]  
                            index.html        1.07 kB          [emitted]  

> Task :...:appengineDeploy
WARNING: In file [/Users/.../appengine/.../build/staged-app/app.yaml]: ('module', 'Field module is deprecated; use service instead.')
Services to deploy:

descriptor:      [/Users/.../appengine/.../build/staged-app/app.yaml]
source:          [/Users/.../appengine/.../build/staged-app]
target project:  [dev...]
target service:  [...]
target version:  [pd-...]
target url:      [https://pd-...-dot-...-dot-dev....appspot.com]


     (add --promote if you also want to make this service available from
     [https://...-dot-dev....appspot.com])

Beginning deployment of service [...]...
#============================================================#
#= Uploading 0 files to Google Cloud Storage                =#
#============================================================#
File upload done.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Instance class (B4_1G) is only allowed with the manual or basic scaling value.
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest
  fieldViolations:
  - description: Instance class (B4_1G) is only allowed with the manual or basic scaling
      value.
    field: version.instance_class

> Task :...:appengineDeploy FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':...:appengineDeploy'.
> com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.AppEngineException: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.operations.cloudsdk.process.ProcessHandlerException: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.AppEngineException: Non zero exit: 1

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':...:appengineDeploy'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$3(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:186)
        at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:268)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:184)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:173)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:109)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
```

...

Comment: Add your ```app.yaml``` file. Also include the command you're running to deploy the app

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! I had to fix the instance error that came up namely:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Instance class (B4_1G) is only allowed with the manual or basic scaling value.
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest
  fieldViolations:
  - description: Instance class (B4_1G) is only allowed with the manual or basic scaling
      value.
    field: version.instance_class

> Task :...:appengineDeploy FAILED
```

I did this by adding

```
<basic-scaling>
    <max-instances>10</max-instances>
 </basic-scaling>
```

to one of the xml files

Comment: "One of the xml- files", Which one? Also some links to the documentation you read  to come to the conclusion would make this answer great :p